# Gradle: Execution failed for task compileReleaseAidl

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-build

I'm having problems updating to Gradle 1.8 in android studio.
When i compile i get this error:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':App Code:compileReleaseAidl'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':App Code:compileReleaseAidl'
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:2.397.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:2.397'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.+'
    compile 'com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.0.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/path/to/keystore")
            storePassword "my-store-password"
            keyAlias "my-key-alias"
            keyPassword "my-key-password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable true
            jniDebugBuild false
        }
    }
}
```

I did some research and found that this problem should have been solved in android build tools 0.6, but i'm experiencing the issue even if i'm using that version.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Thank you krylez, them was not real anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, based on [this gradle article:](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/1904) i change the build.gradle from this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

to this

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```