# Gradle 1.8, build-tools 0.6.3 - Compiling fails on mergeDebugAssets

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Today i was forced to switch to Gradle 1.8 by Android Studio 0.3.0.
This is the issue i already faced before [Execution Failed for Task compileReleaseAIDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307223/gradle-execution-failed-for-task-compilereleaseaidl)
, but now i removed any AIDLs inside the project and i'm still having this error:

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':App Code:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':App Code:mergeDebugAssets'
```

Please note that i also have Facebook SDK library project switched to build-tools 0.6.3.

This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
        classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:2.397.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'newrelic'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:2.397'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.5'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.0.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("/Users/user/Documents/AndroidKeys/Sv01")
            storePassword "my-store-password"
            keyAlias "sv01"
            keyPassword "my-key-password"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable true
            jniDebugBuild false
        }
    }
}
```

How can i compile this project successfully?

*EDIT*: gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#
#Thu Oct 10 22:47:46 CEST 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip
```

*EDIT*: Stacktrace prints this error (That causes the one that i reported before):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.hash(Lcom/google/common/io/InputSupplier;Lcom/google/common/hash/HashFunction;)Lcom/google/common/hash/HashCode;
        at com.android.builder.internal.incremental.FileEntity.getSha1(FileEntity.java:187)
        ........
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009619/gradle-error-could-not-call-incrementaltask-taskaction-on-task-projectmer) answer claims that the issue ended up being a duplicate resource issue.

Comment: how about you run your build with the `--stacktrace` option

Comment: Updated question with stacktrace additional error.